# Question about 2 images, one works as a hover and the other image eases in flips and eases out of the page

Tags: html, css

Working on getting two images, one acting as a website logo (top left of header -- including nav bar) which will be the trigger if a user hovers over. The other as a fish image, that will float in from the left of the screen, flip, and float back out of the screen. Has anyone accomplished this? I need this to be a floating image with an absolute position (to place anywhere on the screen). You can see how I would like this to act, if anyone has done this or knows the best way to achieving this. [sketch up of what I'm going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m999M.png)

Comment: basic css keyframes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: CSS:#slider{
    background: transparent;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    left:-620px;
}

button {
padding: 0;
border: none;
background: none;
}

.open{
    left:50px !important;
    
}
.transition{
        transition: left 1s ease-out;}
 HTML:
<button><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img class="" src="img" width="303.566" height="33.999" alt="align box" align="CENTER"></a></button>
<div id="slider" class="transition">
  <img src="img" width="50%" height="50%">
</div>   Would like to stay away from JS